# Batch HTTP Request and dynamic parsing of values

Tags: http, google-app-engine, batch-processing, randomaccessfile

I have stored 2 [Random-Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) files into the google cloud - [in a Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets); A.file and B.file. I want to make an HTTP request that does the following:

1. Reads 8 bytes from A.file (X1: type long)
2. Reads 4 bytes from A.file (X2: type int)
3. Reads X2 bytes from B.file, starting from the X1 position

My concern is to do that using 1 HTTP request. I have read through the [HTTP - range](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/parameters#range) request and using the [GAE Batch API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch). The problem I have is how to dynamically process the values X1 and X2 on the HTTP request.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware that Google cloud supports random access files.  I believe it only stores sequential access files.  Regardless, you can't do this in one HTTP request.

Comment: Yeah, I have two use 2 HTTP Requests. Thank you for the sequential file information. Do you happen to have any source?